# The longest shortest sequence of series moves

Tags: optimization, chess

Being [inspired](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40837/longest-sequence-of-unique-series-moves), I concoct a question. It starts from a set chess board with only the White pieces. Chess problems in which only one side moves are called seriesmovers.

What is the longest shortest possible sequence of series moves from the prescribed start?

For example, this position can be proven to take a minimum of 7 series moves.

[image]

I am wondering what position/s can be proven to take the longest, assuming White plays as minimally as possible.

To get you started, this position takes a minimum of 79  moves.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower bound:

> 91
>
>  [image]
>
>  7 with king, 40 with pawns, 34 with knights, 2 with each other piece